# Why closed? "How can I find out efficiently when an airline is flying a route?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I don't get why [How can I find out efficiently when an airline is flying a route?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141514/76132) is closed as "as unclear what you're asking". 
[itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141514/how-can-i-find-out-efficiently-when-an-airline-is-flying-a-route#comment351119_141514) understood it. Thanks Itai for supporting me!

> I've come up against this situation before, trying to figure out when in the year is a route actually flown, particularly for very remote places.

I removed question 2.  I'm sorry if you don't like my question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this question is pretty clear, however I've reopened and closed it as a duplicate of [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92284/how-can-i-view-all-of-the-flights-in-out-of-two-cities-across-all-dates) which asks the same question and has plenty of great answers.

Comment: thanks. i edited my post to explain why it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in finding out on which dates a route is flown (which I agree is a pretty clear question), then you should remove the parts about how you are looking for the "cheapest" flights and other irrelevant background which is distracting and makes it unclear what you really want. (Hence I agree that the question in its current state is unclear.)